# Ocaml Variant Types

Tags: ocaml

OCaml types have always really confused me no matter what tutorials/manuals I read. I need to define a type, let's say test, that does contains the following forms:

a type ('a, 'b) test that has one of the forms:
    Empty, T t, N n, Seq [x1...xn]

I know how to do the first 3, but I have absolutely no idea how to define the last form. This is what I have:

```
type ('nonterm, 'term) test =
   | Empty
   | T of 'term
   | N of 'nonterm
   | ????
```

For seq, I need to match the instances of subexpressions x1 to xn. If x = 0, then this is empty. Can anybody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Atticus - I see you are a new user so first: welcome to Stackoverflow!  I have noticed that you haven't voted on or accepted any answers to the questions you have asked so far.  In case you haven't already, you should read the FAQs: http://stackoverflow.com/faq - basically if you like an answer you should vote on it, and if it answers your question sufficiently then you should accept it.

Answer (score 11):

Are the subexpressions of `Seq` also tests?  If so, you can use a list:

```
type ('nonterm, 'term) test =
  | Empty
  | T of 'term
  | N of 'nonterm
  | Seq of ('nonterm, 'term) test list
```

Lists can, of course, be empty.

Comment: Thanks Michael! If possible, would it also be possible for you to explain a little bit about what that last line means? (I'm very new to OCaml and it would be very helpful). And yes, the subexpressions of Seq are also tests, but I'm just curious what would happen if they weren't?

Answer (score 7):

This is an answer to your comment to Michael E:

OCaml variants are composed of constructors with optional arguments.  In the case of Michael's answer, the constructors are: `Empty`, `T`, `N` and `Seq`.  `Empty` takes no arguments, `T` takes a generic type called `'term` and `N` takes a generic type called `'nonterm` (I'll get to `Seq` in a second).  The variant has the type `('nonterm, 'term) test`.  Let's say you want a list of elements of type `('nonterm, 'term) test`:

```
# [Empty; Empty];;
- : ('a, 'b) test list = [Empty; Empty]
```

You'll notice that the type is `('a, 'b) test list`.  (OCaml replaced `nonterm` with `a` and `term` with `b`, but you don't need to worry about that too much).

Now we can see that `| Seq of ('nonterm, 'term) test list` is a constructor called `Seq` that takes a list of elements of type `('nonterm, 'term) test` as an argument.  Now we can do this:

```
# Seq [Empty;Empty];;
- : ('a, 'b) test = Seq [Empty; Empty]
```