# OCaml syntax: what does type 'a t mean?

Tags: ocaml

This is about type definition in OCaml, I find the following syntax puzzling:

```
type 'a t
```

What does it mean in plain English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ocaml Variant Types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777744/ocaml-variant-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since OP has an experience in C++ language, I think the following explanation might be useful. A type declaration of the form:

```
type 'a t
```

is close to the C++

```
template <typename a> class t;
```

For example, `'a list` is a generic list, and `'a` is a type of an element. For concise, we use a single `'`, instead of `template <typename _>` construct. In the OCaml parlance, we use term "parametric polymorphism", instead of "generic programming". And instead of a word template, we say a type constructor. The latter has an interesting consequence. Like in C++ a template instantiation creates a new instances of types, in OCaml concertizing a type variable of a polymorphic type creates a new type, e.g., `int list`, `float list` (c.f., `list<int>`, `float<list>`). So, one can view type constructor `'a list` as an unary function on a type level, it accepts a type, and creates a type. It is possible to have nary type constructors, e.g., `type ('key, 'value) hashtbl` is a binary type constructor, that creates a type for a given `key` and `value` pair.  Moreover, we can see a non parametric types as a nullary type constructors, so `int` constructs the type `int`.

P.S. F# language, a descendant of OCaml, allows to write in both forms: `int t` and `t<int>`

P.P.S. To prevent a possible confusion, I would like to state, that although templates and parametric types are trying to solve the same problems, they still have a few differences. Templates are typed after the instantiation, parametric types before. So parametric type `'a t` is defined *for all* `'a`. If you want to create a type where a type variable is not universally quantified, you can use another mechanism - functors. They are also very close to templates, but they accept a type plus type requirements, a concept in C++ parlance. The concepts are reified in module types in OCaml, and thus a functor is actually a function on a module level, as it accepts a module and produces a module.

Answer (score 6):

This a parametric type declaration.

A type declaration allows you to declare a new datatype:

```
type my_type = int * string

let x : my_type = (42,"Sorry for the inconvenience")
```

Sometimes however, you want a type to be parametric, meaning it takes another type as argument:

```
type 'a container = 'a * string * 'a

let x : int container = (0, "hello", 1)
let y : string container = ("stack", "over", "flow")
```

Now in that case, there is no equal after your type declaration. The meaning of that depends whether if it is in a module's `structure` (like, on top of a `.ml` file) or in a `signature` (e.g. in a `.mli`)

If it is in a structure, it declares a type with no value inside. Which is as useful as an empty set (sometimes it is, but not much). However, if it is in a signature, it means "there exists a parametric definition somewhere, but it is not visible from here".

Suppose there are those two files `a.ml` and `a.mli`:

```
(* a.ml *)
type 'a t = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a t

let empty = Nil
let add x l = Cons (x,l)

(* and so on... *)

(* a.mli *)

type 'a t

val empty : 'a t
val add : 'a -> 'a t -> 'at

(* and so on... *)
```

If in the rest of your program you want to manipulate the `A.t` type, you'll be able to do so only through the `empty` and `add` and other defined functions, but not through directly using `Nil` and `Cons`.